# Chrome set Geolocation API provider

Tags: google-chrome, geolocation

If you use the [HTML5 Geolocation Api](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) in firefox and have no GPS attached to get your current position, firefox uses the nearby wlan ssids to get your position. Firefox sends the ssids via [Geolocation Network Protocol](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/geolocation_network_protocol.html) to http://www.google.com/loc/json and gets a lat/long in response. You can modify the server via `about:config` with the preference key `geo.wifi.uri`.

The chrome geolocation works the [same way](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142065). But I cannot find a setting (no about:config in chrome) where I can change the server for ssid -> location mapping. Is it possible to change the server and where do I change the setting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a little time delay from your question but... you can set the geolocation provider modifying the file "Local State" inside the Chrome installation dir User Data/
There is the geolocation tag and you can set the URL and the token you will use.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific, I don't seem to have any text starting "geo" what so ever in the "Local State" file.

Comment: This workaround seems to work until few version ago of chrome, also http://superuser.com/a/211529/73220 was stated this work around. If you find any other solution please write it