# Set fall back or default geolocation in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, geolocation, geoip

For some reason my home broadband isn't resolving a geolocation inside Chrome, this isn't a problem at work.

Is it possible to set a default or a fall back location in Chrome if the lookup fails?

Happy to hack this in somehow, as its making my testing a nightmare. (Well it means my exception handling is working I suppose..)

Answer (score 2):

No luck [on the official side](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=37452).

On the not so official side, however, there is a "geolocation" object in the configuration file (assuming you are on OSX, otherwise you'll have to look for this file)

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Local State
```

that contains the server address

```
https://www.google.com/loc/json
```

**Maybe** (and I emphasize **maybe**) if you change this address to something you can control, you can feed Chrome with the location you want.

I don't have the opportunity at the moment to test it, but I will in a few hours and will report back my results.

In the meanwhile, if you want to give it a shot...

**EDIT:** I *thought* I would have had a chance in a few hours... turns out I didn't and I won't for the day, sorry...